# Dynamically generating forms with varying number of input controls in java

Tags: java, javascript

As a part of my work  i have to generate a dynamic form with input controls such as text boxes, option button, browse buttons etc by using  the values stored in the database tables. Is there any mechanism for generating and validating a dynamic form with varying number of input control fields!

Answer (score 0):

IDE nowadays gives the support to generate forms from tables.Oracle Application Builder is such a tool that can generate form from back end table.You can go through this tutorial to get an idea about it.

[Oracle Application Builder](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/bldapp_frm.htm)

[Binding Beans and Data in a Java Application
 using NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-binding.html)

Comment: Apart from Oracle Application Builder (APEX), using Oracle Forms you can achieve the same functionality(Oracle Forms is little old technology though).

Comment: @Polppan, are you looking for specific technology solution? But it is much easier to to generate a form using NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Sir..iam working with eclipse IDE and i am a beginner in J2EE, and i want to know if there any mechanism to generate form with input controls from a data base table.

Comment: I seriously doubt whether something is there in Eclipse, but using `Oracle Jdeveloper` you could create forms, controls etc from a database table, it is known as `Application Development Framewrok (ADF)` where you could develop J2EE Applications.